# Implement atomic counter in Memcached without cas

Tags: php, algorithm, transactions, memcached

We have a web page want to limit uo to 100 people can access concurrently, so we use a memcached to implement a global counter, e.g.

We are using `http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php` so there is not `cas`, current code is something like

```
$count = $memcache_obj->get('count');
if ($count < 100) {
   $memcache_obj->set('count', $count+1);
   echo "Welcome";
} else {
   echo "No luck";
}
```

As you can see there is race condition in the above code and but if we are not going to replace `memcached` extension which support `cas`, it is able to support it using PHP code only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your concerned about race conditions, and the count value is completely arbitrary, you can use `Memcache::increment` directly before any business logic.

The [increment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.increment.php) method will return the current value after the incrementation takes place; of which, you can compare results. Increment will also return **false** if the key has yet to be set; allowing for your application to deal with it as needed.

```php
$current = $memcache_obj->increment('count');

if($current === false) {

  // NOT_FOUND, so let's create it
  $memcache_obj->set('count',1); // <-- still risk of race-condition
  echo "Your the first!";

} else if ($current < 100) {

  echo "Hazah! Your under the limit.";

} else {

  echo "Ah Snap! No Luck";
  // If your worried about the value growing _too_ big, just drop the value down.
  // $memcache_obj->decrement('count');

}
```

Answer (score 8):

As answer to "emcconville". This is non-blocking even without CAS.

If your concerned about race conditions, and the count value is completely arbitrary, you can use `Memcache::increment` directly before any business logic.

The [increment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.increment.php) method will return the current value after the incrementation takes place; of which, you can compare results. Increment will also return **false** if the key has yet to be set; allowing for your application to deal with it as needed.

```php
$current = $memcache_obj->increment('count');

if($current === false) {

  // NOT_FOUND, so let's create it
  // Will return false if has just been created by someone else.
  $memcache_obj->add('count',0); // <-- no risk of race-condition

  // At this point 'count' key is created by us or someone else (other server/process).
  // "increment" will update 0 or whatever it is at the moment by 1.
  $current = $memcache_obj->increment('count')
  echo "You are the $current!";

} 
if ($current < 100) {

  echo "Hazah! You are under the limit. Congrats!";

} else {

  echo "Ah Snap! No Luck - you reached the limit.";
  // If your worried about the value growing _too_ big, just drop the value down.
  // $memcache_obj->decrement('count');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function memcache_atomic_increment($counter_name, $delta = 1) {

    $mc = new Memcache;
    $mc->connect('localhost', 11211) or die("Could not connect");

    while (($mc->increment($counter_name, $delta) === false) &&
           ($mc->add($counter_name, ($delta<0)?0:$delta, 0, 0) === false)) {
        // loop until one of them succeeds
    }

    return intval($mc->get($counter_name));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The comments in `Memcache::add` include an [example locking function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.add.php#82277), have you tried it out?